# Double insulated PSU to replace batteries

Tags: power-supply, safety, isolation, insulation

I am building a small power supply with a linear regulator that can be used in place of 9 V blocks. Like a battery, it needs to be floating and hence I want to build it according to double insulated standards. My understanding thereof is as follows:

1. A basic insulation is provided by using insulated wires inside the PSU and obeying creepages/clearances for PCB traces.
2. A second protective insulation is basically provided by putting the whole circuit in an insulating plastic enclosure. Trouble begins as soon as one drills the first hole in this enclosure to connect the PSU output or anything else.
3. To ensure that also the output etc. has a second protective insulation, a suitably rated transformer must be used. These carry the symbols "isolating transformer" or "safety isolating transformer". The datasheet often states "prepared for protection class II" and they typically have their windings on split bobbins.
4. A last consideration is that if the mains cable should come loose inside the equipment it must not come into touch with anything connected to the PSU output. To this end I want to separate the interior of the enclosure into two parts, one on the primary side of the transformer and the other on its secondary side as sketched in the attached drawing. The only electrical connection between both will be on the PCB.

[image: sketch of proposed construction]

My questions are:

- Is my understanding of the requirements for double insulated construction in this particular application correct?
- Do the proposed measures qualify for that purpose?
- Is there anything else I would need to consider?

P.S. Maybe I should add that this is strictly a hobby project and no agency approvals will be needed. I just have the ambition to understand and build it according to the state of the art.

Comment: for a hobby project I probably wouldn't go to such measures. You could just purchase  a wall wart where all the work has been done for you.

Comment: Seriously, you can buy these, or at least you could buy a wall wart with AC output and then add your own rectifiers and regulator in same way as you would do with the PCB transformer you presented.

Comment: I am well aware of these possibilities, but I find good enough reasons to go for building it myself. So that is not the issue. I am interested in learning about how it can be done.

Comment: I would recommend anything you do to design an offline power converter be placed after a 1:1 mains isolation transformer, because working with mains voltages for a hobby project is dangerous. The isolation transformer affords some protection.